# Glide, is it better to use `CustomTarget<Bitmap>()` than `CustomViewTarget<Drawable>` to reduce memory usage?

Tags: out-of-memory, android-glide

Using Glide v4 in android app. The use case is that there is an activity which has a few Fragments in the backstack.
Each Fragment will load one to less than ten images from remote.

Having a kotlin extension for loading image into ImageView:

```
fun ImageView.loadImg(
    imageUrl: String,
    diskCacheStrategy: DiskCacheStrategy = DiskCacheStrategy.AUTOMATIC,
    skipMemoryCache: Boolean = true,
    roundingRadius: Int = 0,
    target: Target<Drawable>? = null,
    requestOptions: RequestOptions = RequestOptions(),
    decodeFormat: DecodeFormat = DecodeFormat.PREFER_RGB_565 
) {
    requestOptions
        .diskCacheStrategy(diskCacheStrategy)
        .format(decodeFormat)
        .apply {
            if (roundingRadius > 0) {
                transform(CenterCrop(), RoundedCorners(roundingRadius))
            }
        }

        Glide.with(this.context)
            .load(imageUrl)
            .apply(requestOptions)
            .skipMemoryCache(skipMemoryCache)
            .apply {
                if (target == null) {
                    into(this@loadImg)
                } else {
                    into(target)
                }
            }
}
```

a typical call in the fragment is like:

```
imageView.loadImg(
            imageUrl = imageUrl,
            roundingRadius = imageRoundingRadius,
            target = object : CustomViewTarget<ImageView, Drawable>(imageView) {
                override fun onLoadFailed(errorDrawable: Drawable?) {
                   imageView.setImageDrawable(null)
                    visibility = View.GONE
                }
                override fun onResourceCleared(placeholder: Drawable?) {
                    imageView.setImageDrawable(null)
                    visibility = View.GONE
                }
                override fun onResourceReady(resource: Drawable, transition: Transition<in Drawable>?) {
                    imageView.setImageDrawable(resource)
                    visibility = View.VISIBLE
                }
            }
        )
```

The problem is whenever one fragment is put in view and add to backstack, the Graphics memory in the profiler shows 50 mg increase. There is not much other data besides the images in the fragment. If comment out the loading image seems reduce a lot.

Not sure if the code loadImage() here is correct? Noticed it is using the ImageView's context in Glide.with(this.context), which is the Activity. Is it a problem?
What is the difference between Glide.with(this.context) and Glide.with(theFragment)?
When is the best time to clear the Target: Glide.with(theFragment).clear(theTarget)?

Noticed there is a CustomTarget(), would using it be helpful for reducing the memory usage if it could take the image size?

code would be like this with target: `Target<Bitmap>`

```
fun ImageView.loadImgAsBitmap(
    imageUrl: String,
    diskCacheStrategy: DiskCacheStrategy = DiskCacheStrategy.AUTOMATIC,
    skipMemoryCache: Boolean = true,
    roundingRadius: Int = 0,
    target: Target<Bitmap>? = null,
    requestOptions: RequestOptions = RequestOptions(),
    decodeFormat: DecodeFormat = DecodeFormat.PREFER_RGB_565 
) {
    requestOptions
            .diskCacheStrategy(diskCacheStrategy)
            .format(decodeFormat)
            .apply {
                if (roundingRadius > 0) {
                    transform(CenterCrop(), RoundedCorners(roundingRadius))
                }
            }

        Glide.with(this.context)
                .asBitmap()
                .load(imageUrl)
                .apply(requestOptions)
                .skipMemoryCache(skipMemoryCache)
                .apply {
                    if (target == null) {
                        into(this@loadImgAsBitmap)
                    } else {
                        into(target)
                    }
                }
}
```

and usage is:

```
imageView.loadImgAsBitmap(imageUrl,
            target = object : CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
                override fun onResourceReady(resource: Bitmap, transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?) {
                    if (resource.height < IMAGE_MIN_SIZE) {// it could check the bitmap size and make use of it
                        imageView.visibility = View.GONE
                        textView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    } else {
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(resource)
                    }
                }
                override fun onLoadCleared(placeholder: Drawable?) {
                    imageView.setImageDrawable(null)
                }
            })
```

This one at least is better that provides the Bitmap size so UI could make use of it.

The question is that is it better to use `CustomTarget<Bitmap>()` than `Target<Drawable>` to reduce memory usage?
How to specify an image size to replace the default `Target.SIZE_ORIGINA`, which says `is very memory inefficient`?

Answer (score 2):

Might be late to answer. I have been studying optimizing the load of images with Glide v4 and came to this good [post](https://proandroiddev.com/how-to-optimize-memory-consumption-when-using-glide-9ac984cfe70f). The author has provided a detailed explanation and suggested solutions with one of the example described is exactly similar to the use case asked in the question.

In summary, instead of calling `Glide.with(context).clear(imageView)` every time the view is going off the screen (move to backstack), the author suggests to use:

- RGB_565 Bitmap format (Glide v4 uses ARGB_8888 by default) with the conditions that the image does not contain transparency and obvious gradient spot. It can reduce the memory consumption as much as 50%.
- `CustomViewTarget`, or `CustomTarget` with a size passing to its constructor or call `override` to specify the desired bitmap dimensions, because `CustomTarget` tends to load original image size when a size is not specified. While the former, `CustomViewTarget`, always load image in accordance to the view dimensions when at least one of its dimension is known.